# Is SO tracking my SO search keywords

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, front-page

This is pretty interesting and my eye stuck on an item. SO showing me a question tagged with [rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rundeck), this is the only tag in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208245). My favorite tag list does not contain this tag.

How this question appeared the front page of SO for me. I heard about [rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rundeck) only two days before. I did some search in google and SO, checked how to configure and create jobs using [rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rundeck).  I regularly check SO, however didn't do anything, sometime just surf the questions. But I never looked at any [rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rundeck) questions previously.

My question is, why did SO suggest something I searched very recently though it's not in my favorite tag list?  Are they building any prediction AI?

Comment: Your question was a bit confusing, but I think I captured what you were trying to ask.  If I didn't interpret you correctly, please rollback and/or edit your question

Answer (score 2):

Your front page should contain *lots* of questions not explicitly tagged with your favorite tags.

Questions tagged with your favorite tags just get highlighted.

Unless [rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rundeck) is in your *ignored* tags, there is no reason for it not to appear in your front page, and questions tagged [rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rundeck) have *always* appeared in your feed. You've just never noticed them, there are after all only 66 of them.